# My jquery lightbox positioning dilemma

Tags: jquery, css, positioning, lightbox, facebox

I have a problem with my jquery popup window that I have on my forum website as shown [here](http://artlessli.com). When I click in 'Log In', the window is all over the place and I cannot for the life of me figure out what I should do.

I'm looking to have the box be centered and for the background overlay to cover the entire background (rather than leave the left side un-darkened).

It appears to be running off a modified version of [Facebox](http://defunkt.io/facebox/).

Before I look into replacing the lightbox altogether, I was wondering if there was a simple fix for something like this. Any help or advice is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
div.Overlay
{
left: 0;
}

div#popup
{
left: 25%;
}
```